# Create variable for percentage change between two values based on group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I want to calculate the percentage difference based on groups in `b` (A,A;B,B;C,C) of a `data.frame`. The new variable `rate` should contain the change in `c` based on the time stamps `a` (i.e. 3 and 7, while the smaller number is always the previous). It should be `NA`, when there is just one time stamp for a given group.

I tried to use the common methods, but i always get a vector of zeros. Example data:

```
a <- c(3,7,3,7,3,7,3,3,7,3,7,3,7,7)
b <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f","f", "g", "g", "h")
c <- runif(14, min=80, max=100)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I  tried the common approach with using `group_by`, `mutate` and `lag` i.e.

```
df %>% group_by(a,b) %>%
  mutate(rate = 100 * (c - lag(c))/lag(c))
```

I also tried `arrange` before using `lag`, but the result i get is always `0`. I think its because there is not a time series which is why we cant use `lag`. There must be an easy way to achieve this with using regular functions.

Comment: You only have 1 row in every `(a,b)` group, so you're going to get `NA` for every result in your example.

Comment: Maybe group_by(a) ...

Comment: @thelatemail, in my case a group is (a,a) or (b,b)  and if you have 3-a-80 and 7-a-100, the change should be 25%

Comment: The point they are both making is that when you group by *both* `a` and `b` in this dataset, there is no change in `c` because there is only one row per group. If you just replace your grouping to `group_by(b)` you should get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you mean `df %>% group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(rate = 100 * (c - lag(c))/lag(c))` ? I tried that aswell but it doesnt work somehow

Comment: It works, but has `NA`'s for the first rows of each group, which is expected since the lag is `NA` by default for these rows. It would be easier to help you if you showed exactly what you want your output to look like.

Comment: @kybazzi. Agree, i didnt explain the output comprehensive enough. I just made a quick sketch to clarify, while Jared already provided the answer. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `lag()` to define your rate, you will end up with "NA" for every b == 3, and the correct value for b == 7 when you group_by "b". Also, `c()` is a Primitive function in R and it's best not to use "c" as the name of a variable.

Is this the outcome you're after?

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(3,7,3,7,3,7,3,3,7,3,7,3,7,7)
b <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f","f", "g", "g", "h")
d <- c(80, 100, runif(12, min=80, max=100))
df <- data.frame(a,b,d)

df %>% group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(rate = 100 * (d - lag(d, default = NA))/lag(d, default = NA))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   b [8]
#>        a b         d   rate
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     3 a      80    NA   
#>  2     7 a     100    25   
#>  3     3 b      88.0  NA   
#>  4     7 b      91.1   3.54
#>  5     3 c      95.1  NA   
#>  6     7 c      82.7 -13.1 
#>  7     3 d      92.6  NA   
#>  8     3 e      84.1  NA   
#>  9     7 e      91.8   9.20
#> 10     3 f      81.9  NA   
#> 11     7 f      93.6  14.4 
#> 12     3 g      88.7  NA   
#> 13     7 g      80.6  -9.11
#> 14     7 h      99.2  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can be more flexible with `ifelse()`'s too, e.g. if you want NA's for cases where you have a single group but zeros for cases where a == 3:

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(3,7,3,7,3,7,3,3,7,3,7,3,7,7)
b <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f","f", "g", "g", "h")
d <- c(80, 100, runif(12, min=80, max=100))
df <- data.frame(a,b,d)

df %>% group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(group_number = n()) %>%
  mutate(rate = ifelse(group_number == 1, NA, ifelse(a == 7, 100 * (d - lag(d, default = NA))/lag(d, default = NA), 0))) %>%
  select(-group_number) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#>        a b         d   rate
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     3 a      80     0   
#>  2     7 a     100    25   
#>  3     3 b      95.8   0   
#>  4     7 b      83.9 -12.5 
#>  5     3 c      87.0   0   
#>  6     7 c      81.5  -6.26
#>  7     3 d      97.0  NA   
#>  8     3 e      99.1   0   
#>  9     7 e      82.6 -16.6 
#> 10     3 f      82.3   0   
#> 11     7 f      96.0  16.7 
#> 12     3 g      99.5   0   
#> 13     7 g      93.4  -6.09
#> 14     7 h      86.8  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! Many thanks :) So the default = NA is what does the job. Thats so unexpected, i need to learn more about lag.